# C# MongoDb BsonDocument.Parse returns System.FormatException

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I parse mongoDb query with nested documents like this

```
{'Username':'Test'},{ 'Age':'25'}
```

or like this

```
$group" : 
{
"_id" : {
"Username" : "$Test"
        }
}
```

because when I use

```
BsonDocument.Parse("{'Username':'Test'},{ 'Age':'25'}");
```

It returns:
**System.FormatException: 'String contains extra non-whitespace characters beyond the end of the document.'**

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in your json, your json should have a root element to parse .Try this

```
 BsonDocument.Parse(@"{user: { Username:'Test', Age:'25'}}");
```

// or maybe this

```
BsonDocument.Parse(@"{users:[{ Username:'Test'},{ Age:'25'}]}");
```

json

```
{
"user":{
  "Username": "Test",
  "Age": "25"
}
}

//or

{"users":[
  {
    "Username": "Test"
  },
  {
    "Age": "25"
  }
]
}
```

Update

it seems to me that you have an error in another json too, change it to this

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "Username": "$Test"
    }
  }
}
```

and try

```
BsonDocument.Parse("{\"$group\":{\"_id\":{\"Username\":\"$Test\"}}}");
```

you can use this classe if you want to deserialize

```
 public class Id
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public Id _id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("$group")]
        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }
```

and using  Newtonsoft.Json

```
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: $group" : 
{
"_id" : {
"Username" : "$Test"
        }
}                                                                     
 And in this case what should I do please?

Comment: you should read about json and expected format for this

Comment: When I used this format
BsonDocument.Parse("[{\"Username\":\"Test\"},{ \"Age\":\"25\"}]");                                          It returns System.FormatException: 'Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'.'

Comment: @dododo Thank you for the hint. I really appreciate it.  But I am a good learner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you cooperation, much appreciated

Comment: @Serge The last thing, would you please explain what @ do and the users refer to what in the example you wrote BsonDocument.Parse(@"{users:[{ Username:'Test'},{ Age:'25'}]}");

Comment: It is jut c# string operator, you need  if you  want to use  'test" instead of   \"Test\". Otherwise you will get a compiller error